# Load property values of attached object in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an object that contains a 1 to 1 relation.

```
public class Container
{
    public virtual Foo Property { get; set; }
}

public class Foo 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Let's assume that we have two different instances of the class Foo saved in the database and that in the initial state Container:s Property is set to Foo1. Now I would like to change that property to Foo2 instead. I do this by:

```
public void SomeMethod(Container container) 
{
    container.Property = new Foo() {
        Id = 2 // Note that this Foo (that is, Foo2) already exists in the database, I just want to change the reference.
    };

    DbUpdate(container)
    DbUpdate.SaveChanges();

    var name = container.Property; // Is null because the properties has not been loaded
}

public void DbUpdate(Container container)
{
    context.Foos.Attach(container.Property);

}
```

The problem with this is that the properties of Foo2 are not loaded. I could rewrite the method to this instead:

```
public void DbUpdate(Container container)
{
    context.Foos.Attach(container.Property);
    context.Entry(container.Property).Reload(); // Explicitly reload the entity

}
```

which solves the problem, however, if no Foo with the given Id exists then the Property (Container.Property) will be set to null.

Is there some other way to load the property values of an attached entity?

**Edit**

To clarify my question I'm adding my current solution which i'm not happy with 
because it needs an extra roundtrip to the db.

```
public void DbUpdate(Container container)
{
    if(context.Entry(container.Property).State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        if(context.Foos.Any(x => x.Id == container.Property.Id))
        {
            context.Foos.Attach(container.Property);
            context.Entry(container.Property).Reload(); // Explicitly reload the entity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is lazy loading kicking in. I can't tell for sure based on your code. Perhaps you can give us some more context? Any way, you can set the lazy loading property on your DbContext class (I think it's located under the Configuration property) to false (= eager loading) or true (= lazy loading).

Comment: Unfortunately I need lazy loading for the rest of the project... good point however.

Comment: *if no Foo with the given Id exists* ... then you can't use this stub entity approach. It always requires existing Ids, or you have to create a new complete entity. If you need the object after `SaveChanges` you may as well fetch it before connecting it to `Container`.

Comment: Calling SaveChanges when attaching an entity that does not exist throws a DbUpdateException. This behaviour is lost when calling the Reload method on the entry. Also, calling reload sets the entity to null when saving. I have updated my question with a possible solution to clarify my question.

Comment: I fail to see the connection between my comment and your last comment. But maybe you didn't mean it to be a response? Anyway, I still don't understand the problem. It seems to want show an object's properties without getting them from the database (??) Why don't you simply fetch a Foo from the database and if isn't there, create a new one, and connect either one with `Container`?